# the function does not seem to change value when called upon 3 times

Tags: vb.net, function

I am writing code in visual basic. the goal of the program is to get a function to randomly pick a string from a array when called upon. the problem is it is not choosing a different value when the button calls it to do so. I have no idea why it is doing this.
Also anyone know how to get multlines to print in a label or text? here is my code.

```
Public Class lbl

Public Function Noun() As String
    Dim rand As New Random
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim nouns() As String = {"boy", "girl", "dog", "town", "car"}
    Dim sentence As String ' used to build a sentence

    index = rand.Next(5)
    sentence = nouns(index)
    Return sentence
End Function

Public Function outs(ByVal n1 As String) As String
    Dim result = n1
    Return result
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    lblRandom.Text = outs(Noun()) & outs(Noun())

    lblRandom1.Text = outs(Noun())

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Shared Function RandomNumber(ByVal lowerBound As Integer, ByVal upperBound As Integer) As Integer
    Return CInt(Math.Floor((upperBound - lowerBound + 1) * Rnd())) + lowerBound
End Function

Public Function Noun() As String
    Dim rand As New Random
    Dim index As Integer = -1
    Dim nouns() As String = {"boy", "girl", "dog", "town", "car"}
    Dim sentence As String ' used to build a sentence
    index = RandomNumber(0, 4)
    sentence = nouns(index)
    Return sentence
End Function

Public Function outs(ByVal n1 As String) As String
    Dim result = n1
    Return result
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    lblRandom.Text = outs(Noun()) & outs(Noun())

    lblRandom1.Text = outs(Noun())

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you re-create a new random generator each time the Noun() function is called. The random number generator should be a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the .NET random number generator generates random numbers based on a seed. The seed is an integer based on the current system date and time. If you call the random number generator a number of times in quick succession, the same seed is likely to be used and the same "random" number will be generated. The solution is to declare the Random object outside of the procedure in which you wish to generate the random number and to pass a seed to its constructor which is built from the current (random) date and time.

To answer your other questions. Label controls will automatically wrap text if the text contains carriage returns. I have added a carriage return below for lblRandom.

To wrap text in a text box, set its Multiline property to True.

The code that @Aly El-Haddad posted will also work but it contains some VB6 legacy code. I have tried to keep it as .NET as possible. I have also eliminated the superfluous "outs" procedure and made it flexible so that you can add or delete elements in the "nouns" array. Note that with the line "index = rand.Next(5)", you are including element 5 of the array which doesn't exist. The upper bound of the zero-based array is 4 so an "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error will be thrown when your random number generator returns 5.

```
 Private myRandom As New Random(CType(DateTime.Now.Ticks Mod Int32.MaxValue, Integer))

 Private Function Noun() As String
     Dim index As Integer
     Dim nouns() As String = {"boy", "girl", "dog", "town", "car"}
     index = myRandom.Next(nouns.GetLowerBound(0), nouns.GetUpperBound(0))
     Return nouns(index)
 End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     lblRandom.Text = Noun() & Constants.vbNewLine & Noun()
     lblRandom1.Text = Noun()
End Sub
```

Comment: In this case, it is not necessary to specify a value for the seed.  The parameterless constuctor for the Random class will use DateTime.Now.Ticks by default.

Comment: You're quite right. The key is to only seed the Random object once. Whether it is with the default seed or a user-initiated seed is irrelevant.

Comment: Therefore the line:

Private myRandom As New Random(CType(DateTime.Now.Ticks Mod Int32.MaxValue, Integer))

may be replaced with:

Private myRandom As New Random()